# CSS element extruding outside of fixed width main container causing background color to cut off

Tags: css

I have a 2-tone design the top container is at 100% width and has a bg color of blue.

The lower part of the page has a bg color of white.

The content width of the site is at 960 with 20px of padding on each side so total 1000px.

My problem is this map on the homepage only, that extrudes outside of the constraints of the 1000px (by design btw).

When i reduce the browser width and scroll horizontally the top container with 100% width cuts off the bg color and it's due to the map container. So i believe that has isolated the problem.

The solution now lies in how to make the map container extrude the main body width constraints without causing the bg color on the top container to cut off when the browser window is reduced and the user scrolls horizontally?

[Here is a screencast](http://youtu.be/rpskEFsjdvI) showing the issue.

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/MARS/pen/vyGBh) with the code.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `min-width` on the header container like so:

```
.container-hdr-home {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  height: 760px;
  background: #2895d5;
}
```

That'll prevent the collpase of that element as the body gets narrower.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: table` to div.container-hdr-home
It makes parent div as wide as inner one